# Manage jquery click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm capturing all the clicks in my "a" elements with this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){....});
```

I want to know if it's possible to discard some events depending on some variable.

For example..

```
If href="http://www.google.es" then alert("google.es")

else if href="http://www.google.com" then do not handle the event and let the browser do whatever it has to do.
```

I don't know if I've explained it very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.href == "http://www.google.es/") alert("google.es");
    else if (this.href == "http://www.google.com/") window.location = this.href;
});
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/5XdkV/

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I thought that it worked as if it always used the e.prevenFeault() behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you could do:

```
$("a[href!='http://www.google.com']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.getAttribute('href') === 'http://www.google.es') alert("google.es");
});
```

And not generate the click event for `google.com` in the first place.

Comment: @lonesomeday: It depends what exactly is in the `href` attribute. I just went by what @sergi said: `If href="http://www.google.es" then alert("google.es")`.

Comment: Oh, I agree. What questioners say and what they *mean* frequently differ, however!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function $(this).attr('href') should give you the href of the anchor tag - which you can then use in the rest of your logic

Answer (score 0):

For your example above,

```
$('a[href*=.es]').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Would make all links that contain .es in the href attribute to not be followed, but leaves the other links alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   if ($(this).attr('href') == 'http://www.google.es') {
      alert('google.es');
      e.preventDefault();
   }
   // if code gets here, it's ok for the browser to handle normally.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions posted so far will work, but they aren't the most flexible.  If you want to match any link that has `google.es` as the hostname, I'd do something like this:

```
$(document.body).delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
    var hostname = this.hostname || $(this).prop('href').split('/')[1];

    if (hostname == 'www.google.es') {
        alert('google.es');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```